pypdf: extract_text in extraction_mode="layout" is working if table is on one page but not working if the table goes to 2nd page
I am using pypdf to extract text and and using this code below. It works if the table is one page (closing the table), but if the table is extended to another page (partially on one page and the rest on a subsequent page), data from the 2nd page only being extracted. Are there any settings I can use, or can I remove page breaks from the PDF. Any help is much appreciated.
txt = page.extract_text(extraction_mode="layout", layout_mode_space_vertically=True)


It might not be easy to handle this in pypdf - I would suggest you use PyMuPDF library instead - it provides the exact functionality you are looking for out of pocket (fetching table data spanning multiple pages). Here's an example: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/table-analysis/join_tables.ipynb

Vikas - That worked well. Thank you So much -- May be you can help me with one more while I was parsing with pymupdf, I am getting error - UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 215-219: character maps to . With pypdf I was using the following line to get rid of those errors "txt = re.sub(f'[^{re.escape(string.printable)}]', '', txt)" are you aware of any way to handle this, or remove/ignore unicode ?
